# Node.js Promises: how to handle timeouts

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I am using Q promises to handle a set of asynchronous functions. One of the functions (promises) uploads files to Azure blob storage. When I upload files of, say, 30MB in size, everything works OK. But when I try to upload larger files (like 150Mb), the files are successfully uploaded but the promise returns an undefined result.

```
upload_creative(files, creativeMIMEType)
// returns a promise. This function uploads the file
  .then(function(result){ // The result object is returned as undefined
    notifyUser(new_post, result)
```

I suspect that the upload of large files takes too longs and the promise times out. Is there a way to manage the timeout and have the promises wait for longer before returning an undefined result?

Comment: A "promise" by itself does not time out. There must be something else. Can you show us the code of `upload_creative` (and the functions it uses for uploading)?